# Bash modifiers in script

Tags: bash, shell, modifier

If I run the following in a bash shell:

```
./script /path/to/file.txt
echo !$:t
```

it outputs file.txt and all is good.

If in my script I have:

```
echo $1:t
```

it outputs /path/to/file.txt:t

How can I get it to output file.txt as per the behaviour I see in a shell? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the first line of the script? Probably starts with `#! ...` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parameter expansion syntax:

```
echo ${1##*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use the [`${1##*/}` expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get the basename of the file with all leading path components removed:

```
$ set -- /path/to/file
$ echo "$1"
/path/to/file
$ echo "${1##*/}"
file
```

You can use this in a script as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "${1##*/}"
```

While `${1##*/}` will work when Bash is called as `/bin/sh`, other Bash features require that you use `#!/bin/bash` at the start of your script. This notation may also not be available in other shells.

A more portable solution is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo `basename "$1"`
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifier only work on [word designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators)